# error: cannot find symbol (using replaceAll ) codenameone

Tags: java, string, codenameone

I´m want to replace a String expression and I receive this error message

```
    error: cannot find symbol
    test1 = testw.replaceAll("/uploads","http://www.anbariloche.com.ar/uploads");
    symbol:   method replaceAll(String,String)
    location: variable testw of type String
```

this is my code

```
    String testw= String.valueOf(element1);


    String test1;
    test1 =     testw.replaceAll("/uploads","http://www.anbariloche.com.ar/uploads");
```

I use Netbeans 8.1

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
Java: 1.7.0_79; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.79-b02
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_79-b15
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86; Cp1252; es_ES (nb)
```

The complete code updated

```
 @Override
protected void beforePortada(Form f) {
    WebBrowser browser=new WebBrowser();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);

    /////Parse
    String URL= "http://www.anbariloche.com.ar/";

    ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest();
    req.setUrl(URL);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
    byte[] data = req.getResponseData();
    if (data == null) {

    }



    XMLParser xmlParser=new XMLParser();
    Element element= null;
    try {
        element = xmlParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Element element1=element.getChildAt(0);


    String testw= String.valueOf(element1);
       ///replace the string
          testw = testw.replaceAll("/uploads/","http://www.anbariloche.com.ar/uploads/");

    browser.setPage(testw,null);
}
 }
```

That's the code updated, I can see where is my mistake
with the String

Comment: @DebosmitRay That is irrelevant

Comment: How are you setting your classpath?

Comment: Your compilation issue is not in code. The issue is String.replaceAll method is not in your java library.

Comment: @Abdelhak No. The issue is how he is building/setting his classpath. He might have another String class taking precedence

Comment: How can I update or change my java library to use thus method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [StringUtil.replaceAll(string, pattern, replace)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/util/StringUtil.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Implementing this in the VM layer is much harder to do in a truly portable way and so we nudge you towards the more portable versions.

Comment: I already have   import static com.codename1.util.StringUtil.replaceAll.....same error

Comment: Import static allows you to call something within your parent class not invoke a method that isn't there on another object.

Comment: Is working now i Use String mystring =StringUtil.replaceAll(string, pattern, replace).

Answer (score 1):

There will not be any error in netbean while coding and it shows runtime error so  StringUtil should be imported and called its replaceAll static method
eg:     StringUtil.replaceAll

Comment: I already imported  import static com.codename1.util.StringUtil.replaceAll

Comment: Please delete this code 
   testw = testw.replaceAll("/uploads/","http://www.anbariloche.com.ar/uploads/");

and replace with 
   testw = StringUtil.replaceAll("/uploads/","http://www.anbariloche.com.ar/uploads/");